# How to merged 3 arrays in one line output in php

Tags: php, arrays

Good Day!

Any suggestions on how can I merged and print 3 arrays in PHP.
I retrieved data from database and put it in ARRAY.

> 1st Array: $date[] = $row['date'];
>
> 2nd Array: $requestor[] = $row['requestor'];
>
> 3rd Array: $die[] = $row['die'];

then I use `foreach` to  print the retrieved data stored from each Array that meets the condition.

```
foreach($date as $item_date){ 
  echo $item_date;
}

foreach($requestor as $item_requestor){ 
  echo $item_date;
}

foreach($die as $item_die){ 
  echo $item_requestor;
}
```

But the result of this code is like this:

```
date1
date2
date3
requestor1
requestor2
requestor3
die1
die2
die3
```

My goal is this one:

```
date1 - requestor1 - die1
date2 - requestor2 - die2
date3 - requestor3 - die3
```

Any Idea oon how can I achieved this output.

TIA

Comment: Are all the arrays of equal length?

Comment: The `key` and `size` will be same for ll of them?

Comment: The Size of the array will depend on the no. of entries that will meet the condition in the query. and Yes also, all 3 arrays will be in the same size since they will came from 1 table only.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it manually count on loop like this

```
$count = count($date)-1;
```

then loop through this

```
for ( $i=0;$i <= $count; $i++ ) {
   $arrayGenerate[$i] = array(
        'row1' => $data[$i].'-'.$requestor[$i].'-'.$die[$i]
   );
}
```

like this

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
for($i = 0; $i <= count($date); $i ++) {
    echo $date[$i]." - ".$requestor[$i]." - ".$die[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the all 3 arrays count/size is same & you want it in this fashion

```
<?php
    $a = array('1','2','3');
    $b = array('4','5','6');
    $c = array('7','8','9');

    for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++)
    {
        echo $merged_arr_str = $a[$i] . " - " . $b[$i] . " - ". $c[$i] . " <br/>"; 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

**Example One:-**

```
$date = array('date1','date2','date3','date4');
$requestor = array('requestor1','requestor2','requestor3','requestor4');
$die = array('die1','die2','die3','die4');

$count = max(count($date), count($requestor), count($die));
$newarray = array();
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
   //Demo1
   if (isset($date[$i])) $newarray[] = $date[$i];
   if (isset($requestor[$i])) $newarray[] = $requestor[$i];
   if (isset($die[$i])) $newarray[] = $die[$i];

   //Demo2
   //echo $ouput = $date[$i].'-'.$requestor[$i].'-'.$die[$i];
}
//array merge output
var_dump($newarray);
```

**Example Two**

```
$date = array('date1','date2','date3','date4');
$requestor = array('requestor1','requestor2','requestor3','requestor4');
$die = array('die1','die2','die3','die4');
$arrays = array($date, $requestor, $die);
array_unshift($arrays, null);
$n = call_user_func_array('array_merge', call_user_func_array('array_map', $arrays));
print_r($n);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($date); $i ++) {
        echo $date[$i]." - ".$requestor[$i]." - ".$die[$i];
    }
```

this loop will iterat untill last element of date array.if you want to put equal to sign then you have to initialize `$i` with 1.

```
exm. if $i = 0 then $i < count($date) 
                OR
     if $i = 1 then $i <= count($date)
```